# Galois: Why does $\{1,f,f^2\}$ correspond to $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$?

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions

I'd like to discuss [this example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_Galois_theory#Example_2) from the wikipedia article.

It claims that the group $\{1,f,f^2\}$ corresponds to $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$. But then it must hold true that the fixed field $Fix(\{1,f,f^2\})=\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$ by Galois correspondence.

I see that happening for $1,f$ but for $f^2$ it's $f(\omega)^2=\omega^2$, isn't it? It's not fixed.

Where am I thinking wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well but you are conflating $(f(\omega))^2=f(\omega)×f(\omega)=\omega×\omega$ with $f^2(\omega)=f(f(\omega))=f(\omega)=\omega$.

Comment: Indeed, thank you for resolving my confusion.

Comment: Glad I could help, I understand the confusion, in many places $g^2(x)$ is indeed $g(x)×g(x)$. In Galois groups however, $g^2(x)=g(g(x))$, for elements $g$ of a Galois group